# I tried pip installing spyder terminal in windows and now spyder 4.1.3 won't open

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, spyder

I have used matlab, but I am only 2 weeks into Python. I downloaded anaconda 3.7 and am using spyder 4.1.3. I was following a youtube tutorial on python. I was doing well until the guy access the cmd prompt (I use Windows 10) from within his IDE.

I didn't know how to so I googled it and to do so I found on pypi.org that all I had to do was run `pip install spyder-terminal` in the cmd prompt. I tried this but at the end it said that I had a permissions error and to try the --user option. I copied and pasted the exact error and saw on git hub, to create an environment or run `python -m pip install --user [INSERT PACKAGE NAME]`.

I don't really understand hat an environment is so I did the second `--user` way. I ran `python -m pip install --user spyder terminal` I got an error about a location not being in the path variable, so i just copied the file location that it referenced and copied it the the path. I then went to open up spyder 4.1.3 and i got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in 
from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 201, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 53, in 
requirements.check_qt()
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
import qtpy
File "C:\Users\Aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in 
raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found"
```

I tried opening it again and got the same error. I then tried uninstalling an dre-installing spyder in the anaconda navigator and got the same error. I tried removing the location I added to path and running "pip uninstall spyder-terminal", it said it was removed and I go the same error.

If possible, I am seeking specific steps in layman's terms, because all my knowledge thus far has come from the first 2 hours of a "cool things in python" type video.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's easier to read code or traceback segments when you write format them not as text but as a code block. You can do that by enclosing it with three backticks - in the editing view is an example below the text area.

Comment: [`conda`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda) and `pip` are different Python package managers. Don't mix them up unless you know what you're doing. If you want to keep it simple, use either pip or conda, not both at the same time. Also, why not just use `cmd` or `ps` until you are comfortable with Spyder and its plugin system?